# Google sheets get file name from url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm trying to create a function in google sheets to get the workbook name from url link.

```
function getFileName(id) {
var file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(id)
var fileName = file.getName();    
return fileName;  
}
```

I receive message

"Error
You do not have permission to call openByUrl"

I tried

```
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
```

I receive the same sort of message

"No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use this as a custom function as it requires authorization.

See the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

> If your custom function throws the error message `You do not have permission to call X service.`, the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.
>
> To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.