# Get sheet name with url by getting range from a cell

Tags: google-sheets

How can I get the sheet name with formula/custom function by getting the cell range which will contain the URL in a spreadsheet?

I'm using the following code, but I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

```
  function getFileNames() {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Links");
        var links = sheet.getRange("B3:B").getValues();
        var filenames = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var url = links[i][0];
    if (url != "") {
        var filename = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(links[i][0]).getName();
       filenames.push([filename]);
   }
 }
  var startRow = 3; // print in row 2 since row 1 is the header row
  var fileNameColumn = 3; // Column B = column 2
  var destination = sheet.getRange(startRow, fileNameColumn, filenames.length, filenames[0].length);
  destination.setValues(filenames);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was already a similar question in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082742/google-sheets-get-file-name-from-url), I believe that you won't be able to call it as a custom function if it requires authorization  according to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services).

I also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395194/get-filename-from-url-google-sheet) that shows how to retrieve the name of the spreadsheet from cells by having the URL.

Comment: Hello, Gabriel. I have updated this question with the code and the error

Answer (score 2):

Length of undefined means that your links is undefined. Check the below script for a sample working code:

#### Script:

```
function getFileNames() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Links");
  var links = sheet.getRange("B3:B").getValues();

  // 1st: get a 1D array representation of the links (flat)
  // 2nd: remove the empty rows (filter)
  // 3rd: return the spreadsheet names of the remaining rows to filenames
  var filenames = links.flat().filter(String).map(link => {
    return [SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(link).getName()];
  });

  var startRow = 3; // data will start at 3rd row
  var fileNameColumn = 3; // data will be written at 3rd column which is column C
  sheet.getRange(startRow, fileNameColumn, filenames.length, filenames[0].length)
       .setValues(filenames);
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I'm looking more like in a A1 the name and in B1 the URL. Also, the result should be the Spreadsheet name, not the sheet (tab) name.

Comment: Hi @mau, you basically said sheet name so I provided it. File is spreadsheet while tab is sheet. Also, if you are expecting an apps script solution, include the apps script tag.

Comment: @mau, I have modified and provided a working script above. See sample output. I modified your comments are they are off. 3 for both row and column will write to C3:C. And since your range inputted was B3:B, I assume the correct orientation is C3:C, not A2:A or C2:C